# Namenode is not running without errors in cygwin

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop2.2, ssh, java in my cygwin. When I tried to run the namenode using this `sbin/hadoop.daemon.sh` start namenode", I'm getting no errors but when I run jps command once, I can see the namenode running once. After 10 sec it is not running.

Comment: can you post your logs .....

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can see below informatin in the name node logs.

ulimit -a for user Pranay
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2022
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited